# JQuery grouping spans

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following spans inside a DIV

```
<div class="itens">
  <span data-type="car" data-value="1"></span>
  <span data-type="car" data-value="2"></span>
  <span data-type="car" data-value="3"></span>

  <span data-type="bus" data-value="1"></span>
  <span data-type="bus" data-value="2"></span>

  <span data-type="airplane" data-value="1"></span>
</div>
```

And I need to iterate through the spans and group by type. In the end, I need to have a hash like this

```
{
  car: [1,2,3],
  bus: [1, 2],
  airplane: [1]
}
```

I've tried some snippets but I can't solve this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery `[attribute=value]` selector for each data type, then iterate each one with .each

```
const store = {
    car: [],
    bus: [],
    airplane: [],
};

$("[data-type='car']").each(function() {
    store.car.push(this.getAttribute('data-value'));
});
$("[data-type='bus']").each(function() {
    store.bus.push(this.getAttribute('data-value'));
});
$("[data-type='airplane']").each(function() {
    store.airplane.push(this.getAttribute('data-value'));
});
```

For a more general case, we want to initialize the arrays as we discover types that don't have one yet.

```
const store = {};

$(".items span").each(function() {
    let dataType = this.getAttribute('data-type');
    //see if the array for the type has been defined yet
    if(!store.hasOwnProperty(dataType)) {
        store[dataType] = [];
    }
    store[dataType].push(this.getAttribute('data-value'));
});
```

Comment: but is there a way to iterate dynamically ? because I have a lot of spans with many types

Comment: Try my answer @user1439898

Answer (score 0):

Try using this Javascript Code -

```
var resultArr = new Object();
$('div.itens span').each(function(key, val){
    var typeVal =  $(val).attr('data-type');
  var value = $(val).attr('data-value');
    if(resultArr.hasOwnProperty(typeVal)){
    resultArr[typeVal].push(value);
  }
  else{
    resultArr[typeVal] = [value];
  }
});
```